# How to cut specific word from output using substring index in c#

Tags: c#, .net, substring, indexof

I got data type convertion error.

```
System.FormatException: The string '11 ICU ECLH' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index '3'.
   at System.DateTimeParse.Parse(ReadOnlySpan`1 s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
   at System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )
   at DataTransformLib.CommonFunctions.GetTypeValue(Object value, OutputDataType outputDataType) in F:\emr-pipeline\EMRData\DataTrans\CommonFunctions.cs:line 24
```

But i need to return `The string '11 ICU ECLH' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`only. how to do that using substring in c#.net

Comment: Try to use Regex

Comment: Can you give specific link?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1):

From your stack trace it seems you're trying to convert the string to a DateTime object.  If you want the error returned, you could wrap it in a try/catch like this:

```
try
{
    return Convert.ToDateTime(yourValue);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return ex.Message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the Try/Catch approach proposed by Cornelius above would work, you can avoid throwing exceptions by using `DateTime.TryParse`. It returns a boolean with the state of the conversion. You already have the string, so you can return a custom message to the user using that.

```
string date = "01/01/2000";
DateTime parsedDateTime;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(date, out parsedDateTime)
    Console.WriteLine($"The string {date} is not a valid DateTime"); //for example
```